# Deny read access to a path using authz

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

I am trying to deny a user access to a certain path in an SVN repository.

According to [the documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) this is done by setting the username to empty.

> ```
> [calc:/branches/calc/bug-142/secret]
> harry =
> ```

Also, though nowhere mentioned in the documentation, I [found](http://grokbase.com/t/subversion/users/1019eey8h0/problem-implementing-path-based-authorization-with-authz) this piece of information:

> If I remember correctly, you cannot have less than global read
>   permissions on the repository's root if you're on SVN 1.5 or later.

This is allegedly [fixed](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3242) in 1.7, still I decided to start with read access for everyone and then to deny access to one path.

This is the configuration of my SVN vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

  <Location />
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /var/repositories/

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Repositories"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwd/rep
    Require user andre

    # Google: svn secure connection truncated
    SVNPathAuthz Off
  </Location>

  <Location /test/>
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwd/rep-test
    Require valid-user
    SVNPathAuthz On
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/passwd/authz-test
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Inside the repository `https://svn/test/` there is a directory `test2`.

This is my current `authz-test` file, which is unable to stop user `andre` from accessing the directory `test2` and its content:

```
[/]
* = rw

[/test2]
andre =
[/test2/]
andre =
[test/test2]
andre =
[/test/test2]
andre =
[test/test2/]
andre =
[/test/test2/]
andre =
[test:/test/test2]
andre =
[test/:/test2]
andre =
[test:/test2/]
andre =
[test/:/test2/]
andre =
[test:test2]
andre =
[test/:test2]
andre =
[test:test2/]
andre =
[test/:test2/]
andre =
```

When I comment the `* = rw`, access to the repository is immediately denied, so at least the file isn't being ignored completely. I am using Subversion 1.7.8.

Answer (score 0):

1. First `Locaton` is **terribly bad idea!!!**
2. For second `Locaton`  you **have not** any SVNParentPath|SVNPath - location broken. In case of using SVNParentPath and creating **test2 repository** `[test2:/]` will be correct path

Comment: I *do have* `SVNParentPath` and what is better than `Location`?

Comment: @AndreKR - you have in first location only, which is not inherited in second location. SVN* command is not better/worse, it's just a) a must b) inside location... and intersected SVN-locations (can|will) produce **unpredictable results**